# Node date in a different language?

Tags: 6, nodes, datetime, i18n-l10n

I use the following code to display the date in my node template:

```
<?php echo date("j F Y", $created); ?>
```

But I need to display the months in a different language, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/6) function that allows you add you own format and Drupal will translate it into the currently website site language.

Comment: Or [date_format_date()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--date--date_api.module/function/date_format_date/6) (the tags suggest the OP's using date.module).

Comment: And what to do if we only want to translate the month and not the whole website?

Comment: You can either use the t function or, format_date accept a langcode parameter that will translate your month if the language is activated in your web site.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ;-)
Whatever the $language parameter, the format_date() function doesn't change (for me) the language of the date.